# Understanding Equivalence and Relations

Tags: equivalence-relations

Can someone please explain these answers? I have reviewed the slides and read about properties of equality but I still don't understand how to apply it to these sets.

For each the following relations on the set of integers list all that apply 
(Reflexive, Symmetric, Antisymmetric, Transitive, or none):

$R1 = \{(a, b)\mid a \neq b\}$; Solution: Symmetric

$R2 = \{(a, b)\mid a < b\}$; Solution: Antisymmetric, Transitive

$R3 = \{(a, b) \mid a = b\text{ or }a = b + 1\}$; Solution: Reflexive, Antisymmetric

$R4 = \{(a, b) \mid a = b\}$; Solution: Reflexive, Symmetric, Antisymmetric, Transitive

$R5 = \{(a, b) \mid a = 2b\}$; Solution: Antisymmetric

$R6 = \{(a, b) \mid a < 10 - b\}$; Solution: Symmetric

Comment: There's an awful lot here; what's tripping you up?

Comment: The question isn't "Which of these are equivalence relations"... the question is "which of these properties does each relation satisfy?"

Comment: Well, this is for a summer course and the person teaching it is working on a PhD and this is the first class they have taught. They haven't been very well with explaining things and have had to rush over a lot and I don't understand these properties towards a set like (a,b). For instance, I know Symmetric is a relation if (a, b) is in R whenever (b, a) is in R, for some (a, b) is in R but that doesn't help me.

Comment: Why does that not help you? What is giving you problems when you try to check if one of the given relations satisfy it?

Comment: I don't understand how to apply them. I know this is probably very basic but I just don't get even the first problem. Is it saying that for (a, b) where (a, b) can be anything, it can be symmetrical? And if that's the case, couldn't it also be asymmetrical for other values of (a, b)? Sorry, I am lost altogether.

Comment: When we say that a relation is symmetric, we're saying something about every $(a,b)$.  In the case of the first problem, we note that if $a≠b$, then we have to have $b≠a$.  Also, if it's not the case that $a≠b$, then we can't have $b≠a$.  Because of this, the relation given by "≠" is symmetric.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: Why prove in two directions?

Comment: @CameronBuie for clarity; certainly not out of necessity for proof. Interestingly though, the definition is usually given as $(a,b)$ is a member if and only if $(b,a)$ is a member, though the "if" alone would be sufficient since (a,b) are arbitrary.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: I have personally never seen the definition given as "if and only if". What texts have you seen that in? I'd like to avoid them, since they seem to carry unnecessary information. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's review what each property means.  Your question deals with relations on the integers; so, let's say that we are working with a relation $R\subseteq\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$.

### Symmetric:

$R$ is called *symmetric* if for all $(a,b)\in R$, we also have $(b, a)\in R$.

For instance, $R_1$ is symmetric: if $(a,b)\in R_1$, then $a\neq b$, which implies $b\neq a$ and therefore $(a,b)\in R_1$.

On the other hand, $R_3$ is not symmetric; $(5,4)\in R_3$, but $(4,5)\notin R_3$.

### Antisymmetric:

$R$ is called *antisymmetric* if whenever $(a,b)\in R$ and $a\neq b$, we have $(b,a)\notin R$.

So, for instance, $R_1$ is not antisymmetric; $(3,5)$ and $(5,3)$ are both elements of $R_1$.

On the other hand, $R_5$ is antisymmetric: if $a=2b$ and $a\neq 0$, then $b\neq 2a$ and so $(b,a)\notin R_5$; if $a=0$ and $a=2b$, then $a=b=0$, so it is fine.

### Transitive:

$R$ is called *transitive* if whenever $(a,b)\in R$ and $(b,c)\in R$, we also have $(a,c)\in R$.

For instance, $R_1$ is not transitive: $(3,5)\in R_1$ and $(5,3)\in R_1$, but $(3,3)\notin R_1$.

On the other hand, $R_2$ *is* transitive: if $(a,b),(b,c)\in R$, then $a<b$ and $b<c$; therefore $a<c$, and $(a,c)\in R_2$.

### Reflexive:

$R$ is called *reflexive* if $(a,a)\in R$ for all $a$.

So, $R_1$ is not reflexive: if $(a,a)\in R_1$, then $a\neq a$... which is clearly not true.

On the other hand, $R_3$ is reflexive; since any $a\in\mathbb{Z}$ satisfies $a=a$ (and, therefore, either $a=a$ or $a=a+1$), we have $(a,a)\in R_3$.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This does, I wish he would have explained it like this. It's a lot easier when integers are plugged into the properties. Sorry for any trouble.

Comment: "On the other hand, R3 is not symmetric; (5,4)∈R3, but (4,5)∉R3."    How is (4,5) not in R3?

Comment: @HermesTrismegistus: we are working with ordered pairs.  So $(4,5)$ is not in R3 because $4 \neq 5$ and $4 \neq 5+1$.  The fact that $5=4+1$ is not important

Comment: @HermesTrismegistus Exactly as Ross says.  $R_3$ is the set of all _ordered pairs_ $(a,b)$ such that either $a=b$ or $a=b+1$. Plugging in $a=4$ and $b=5$ does not satisfy either condition, and so $(4,5)\notin R_3$.

Comment: Thanks guys. I will just have to keep working with this. I really appreciate the time you have spent trying to help me.

Comment: If you only have two pairs, (a,b), how can it be transitive without having a third?

Comment: ?  Your sample space here is all the integers - the relations are given in terms of formulas.  So, $R_1$ is the collection of _all_ $(a,b)$ such that $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $a\neq b$; it includes infinitely many points.

Answer (score 1):

That’s potentially $6\cdot 4=24$ properties to check, so let me just do a sample. I’ll start with $R_1$.

- **Reflexive?** In order for $R_1$ to be reflexive, it has to be true that if $n$ is any integer, then $\langle n,n\rangle\in R_1$. This means that $n\ne n$. Obviously that’s not true for every integer, since in fact it’s not true for *any* integer. Thus, $R_1$ is not reflexive.
- **Symmetric?** In order for $R_1$ to be symmetric, it has to be true that if $m$ and $n$ are integers, and $\langle m,n\rangle\in R_1$, then $\langle n,m\rangle\in R_1$ as well. Suppose that $\langle m,n\rangle\in R_1$; by the definition of $R_1$ this means that $m\ne n$. But of course in that case $n\ne m$, so (again by the definition of $R_1$) $\langle n,m\rangle\in R_1$. Thus, $R_1$ is symmetric. This is just a fancy way of saying that if $m\ne n$, then $n\ne m$.
- **Antisymmetric?** In order for $R_1$ to be antisymmtric, the following has to be true: if $m$ and $n$ are integers, $\langle m,n\rangle\in R_1$, and $\langle n,m\rangle\in R_1$, then $m=n$. Suppose that we take $m=0$ and $n=1$. $0\ne 1$, so by definition $\langle 0,1\rangle\in R_1$. And $1\ne 0$, so by definition $\langle 1,0\rangle\in R_1$. Can we conclude from this that $0=1$? Obviously not, so $R_1$ is not antisymmetric.
- **Transitive?** In order for $R_1$ to be transitive, the following has to be true: if $k,m$, and $n$ are integers, $\langle k,m\rangle\in R_1$, and $\langle m,n\rangle\in R_1$, then $\langle k,n\rangle\in R_1$. Take $k=0$, $m=1$, and $n=0$. Then $0\ne 1$, so $\langle k,m\rangle=\langle 0,1\rangle\in R_1$, and $1\ne 0$, so $\langle m,n\rangle=\langle 1,0\rangle\in R_1$, but $\langle k,n\rangle=\langle 0,0\rangle$, and $\langle 0,0\rangle$ is **not** in $R_1$, because it’s obviously not true that $0\ne 0$.

Now let’s take a look at $R_3$: $\langle m,n\rangle\in R_3$ if and only if $m=n$ or $m=n+1$.

- **Reflexive?** In order for $R_3$ to be reflexive, it has to be true that if $n$ is any integer, then $\langle n,n\rangle\in R_3$. This means that $n=n$ or $n=n+1$, which is clearly true, so $R_3$ is reflexive.
- **Symmetric?** In order for $R_3$ to be symmetric, it has to be true that if $m$ and $n$ are integers, and $\langle m,n\rangle\in R_3$, then $\langle n,m\rangle\in R_3$ as well. Suppose that $\langle m,n\rangle\in R_1$; by the definition of $R_1$ this means that $m=n$ or $m=n+1$. If $m=n$, then $n=m$, and $\langle n,m\rangle\in R_3$, but what if $m=n+1$? Then $n=m-1$, so $n\ne m$ and $n\ne m+1$, and therefore $\langle n,m\rangle\notin R_3$. To give a concrete, specific counterexample, take $m=1$ and $n=0$; then $m=n+1$, so $\langle m,n\rangle=\langle 1,0\rangle\in R_3$, but $0\ne 1$ and $0\ne 1+1$, so $\langle 0,1\rangle\notin R_3$. Thus, $R_3$ is not symmetric.
- **Antisymmetric?** In order for $R_3$ to be antisymmtric, the following has to be true: if $m$ and $n$ are integers, $\langle m,n\rangle\in R_3$, and $\langle n,m\rangle\in R_3$, then $m=n$. Suppose that $\langle m,n\rangle\in R_3$ and $\langle n,m\rangle\in R_3$. The first of these means that $m$ is either $n$ or $n+1$. If $m=n+1$, then obviously $n=m-1$, so $n\ne m$ and $n\ne m+1$, and therefore $\langle n,m\rangle\notin R_3$, contrary to hypothesis. Thus, it must be that $m=n$, and it follows that $R_3$ is antisymmetric.
- **Transitive?** In order for $R_3$ to be transitive, the following has to be true: if $k,m$, and $n$ are integers, $\langle k,m\rangle\in R_3$, and $\langle m,n\rangle\in R_3$, then $\langle k,n\rangle\in R_3$. Take $k=2$, $m=1$, and $n=0$. Then $k=2=1+1=m+1$, so $\langle k,m\rangle=\langle 2,1\rangle\in R_3$, and $m=1=0+1=n+1$, so $\langle m,n\rangle=\langle 1,0\rangle\in R_3$, but $\langle k,n\rangle=\langle 2,0\rangle\notin R_3$, because $2\ne 0$ and $2\ne 0+1$. This example shows that $R_3$ is not transitive.

The details of checking each of the four properties for each of the other four relations will be different, but this should at least give you a start on how to think about the problem. Note that showing that a relation $R$ **does** have a property requires giving a general argument covering all possible cases; to show that $R$ does **not** have a property, on the other hand, you need only find a single counterexample to the property, one lonely instance in which it fails.

Answer (score 0):

Let me just look at a few, to show you what's going on.

---

Consider $R_1$.

It is symmetric, because whenever $a\ne b$, then $b\ne a$--so whenever $\langle a,b\rangle \in R_1,$ then $\langle b,a\rangle \in R_1$.

In order for $R_1$ to be reflexive, we'd need to know that $\langle a,a\rangle \in R_1$ for all integers $a$, meaning $a\ne a$ for all integers $a$. You should be able to think of some counterexamples for that, I hope.

In order for $R_1$ to be antisymmetric, we'd need to know that whenever $\langle a,b\rangle ,\langle b,a\rangle \in R_1,$ then $a=b,$ meaning that $a\ne b$ and $b\ne a$ together imply that $a=b$.

For $R_1$ to be transitive, we would need to know that whenever $\langle a,b\rangle ,\langle b,c\rangle \in R_1,$ then $\langle a,c\rangle \in R_1,$ meaning that $a\ne b$ and $b\ne c$ together imply $a\ne c$. I leave a counterexample to you.

---

Consider $R_3$.

It should be clear that $\langle a,a\rangle \in R_3$ for all integers $a$--since $a=a$--so $R_3$ is reflexive.

$R_3$ isn't symmetric, since if $a=b+1$ (which happens sometimes when $a$ and $b$ are integers), then we have neither $b=a$ nor $b=a+1$. Sometimes, then, we can have $\langle a,b\rangle \in R_3$ with $\langle b,a\rangle \notin R_3$. (Can you think of any examples?)

Now, suppose $\langle a,b\rangle ,\langle b,a\rangle \in R_3$. Since $\langle b,a\rangle \in R_3,$ then $b=a$ or $b=a+1,$ so it is impossible for $a=b+1.$ Since $\langle a,b\rangle \in R_3$ and $a\ne b+1,$ it follows that $a=b.$ Thus, $R_3$ is antisymmetric.

Suppose $\langle a,b\rangle ,\langle b,c\rangle \in R_3$. If $a=b$ or $b=c,$ then we can conclude $\langle a,c\rangle \in R_3,$ but what about if $a\ne b$ and $b\ne c$? Well then $a=b+1$ and $b=c+1$, so $a=c+2$, and so $\langle a,c\rangle \notin R_3$. Thus, $R_3$ is not transitive.

---

Does that help clear things up?

Comment: Kind of, but for R3 doesn't OR mean that it can be either one or the other? That it doesn't have to be both?

Comment: @Hermes: Indeed, it doesn't have to be both (in fact, it *can't* be both, in this case), but it may be either one. For example, $\langle 9,8\rangle\in R_3,$ since $9=8+1,$ but also $\langle 9,9\rangle\in R_3,$ since $9=9$.

Comment: Which part of my $R_3$ discussion is your biggest sticking point?

Comment: Well, if it only has to satisfy one condition and the ordered pair, wouldn't it be symmetric since (a,b) could be (9,9)? Or does the ordered pair (a,b) have to satisfy all possible values?

Comment: In order to be symmetric, we have to know that for ***every*** $\langle a,b\rangle\in R_3,$ we also have $\langle b,a\rangle\in R_3$. Using the example I gave above, we know that $\langle 9,8\rangle\in R_3.$ However, $\langle 8,9\rangle\notin R_3,$ since neither $8=9$ nor $8=9+1$ is true.

Comment: That makes sense. Sorry for all the basic questions. This class did not come with an assigned book and everything has been addressed through one session of lecture per week over a 4 week period for Discrete Math.

Comment: Quite all right--this site is meant for questions. Also, I know how frustrating the short time can be (from the other direction, though).